# Want to scrape a table on a page with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape a table on a page into a dataframe with columns name of "Contracts" and "Funding Rate".(https://www.binance.com/en/futures/funding-history/1)

This is what i have tried so far but still can't work out. Appreciate if anyone can help me out of this.

```
import time

import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.binance.com/cn/futures/funding-history/0")
time.sleep(5)
# headers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="tablesorter-headerRow"][2]/th/div')
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bnc-table-tbody"]')
```

But it returned me some errors.

Comment: Hi @CHOINCE1001 it'd be nice if you told us what the errors were as well.

Comment: You can get all the data with one post call. If you look at the network, you will see that they get data from API. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xPath selector should be: `//*[@class="bnc-table-tbody"]`

HTML:

[image: html example]

Then you can iterate the table rows and convert into a `DataFrame`:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="bnc-table-tbody"]')
data = []
for tr in table.find_elements_by_xpath('tr'):
    columns = tr.find_elements_by_xpath('td')
    data.append({
        'Contract': columns[0].text,
        'Funding Rate': columns[2].text
    })
# Convert lits of dictionaries into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Appreciate for your answer. It perfectly solves my problem!

Comment: Does anyone have an update? I can't get table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="bnc-table-tbody"]') to work

Answer (score 1):

Watching the Network activities in Developer Tools (`Ctrl + Shift + I`), it appears that the web page is making a `POST`requests to API, that returns a `JSON` data used to populate the table. This means you do not need `selenium`, `requests` alone can handle the task. We can get all the data with one post call:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

API_URI = ' https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/future/common/get-funding-rate-history'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update({'User-Agent':'Just Another Human'})
    payload = {'symbol': "BTCUSDT", 'page': 1, 'rows': 1276} # There are 1276 rows
    
    response = session.post(API_URI, json=payload)
   

data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
```

NetWorK[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your method. But the symbol column showed the same name which is "BTCUSDT" instead of different symbols names. Are there anyway to correct it ?

Comment: Can you paste expected results as dummies data of three rows?

Answer (score 0):

access `tr` `td` elements using loop

```
(//div[@class='bnc-table-wrapper']//table//tbody/tr)[index]//td//text()

#this will give the text of td elements try this an loop tr elements
```